# Не могу считать с фаила json данные

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне необходимо написать функцию, которая считает эти данные из файла. Параметр функции - имя файла.
Я делаю следующее:

```
def open_json_data("data.json"):
    with open("data.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
        new_data = json.load(json_file)
    return new_data

dict_list = open_json_data()
```

В итоге выдает ошибку:

```
def open_json_data("data.json"):
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Часть кода в фаиле json:

```
[
{"name": "Alhazen",
 "years": "c. 965 – c. 1040"
 {"name": "Archimedes",
 "years": "c. 287 BC – 212 BC."}
```

]

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос ошибку и файл data.json?

Comment: сделайте просто open_json_data()

Comment: В условии написано сделать именно через функцию

Comment: если через функцию, которая принимает на вход адрес файла, тогда def open_json_data(file_path = "data.json"):
    with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:

Comment: Изучите синтаксис функций еще раз.

Comment: @Stud200891, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Stud200891, вы не приняли ни одного ответа из предложенных для __всех__ ваших 9-ти вопросов. Вам действительно не подошел ни один из них или же вы сознательно нарушаете правила форума??

Answer (score 2):

Идея использования параметров функции в том, чтобы можно было вызывать одну функцию с **разными** значениями параметров. Вы же жестко закодировали единственное имя файла. Сделайте лучше так:

```
def open_json_data(filename="data.json", encoding="utf-8"):
    with open(filename, "r", encoding=encoding) as json_file:
        new_data = json.load(json_file)
    return new_data
```

PS причина `SyntaxError` в том, что вместо имени параметра функции вы используете константную строку (литерал).

Answer (score 0):

Если код надо будет часто редактировать или много где открывать файл, делайте так:

```py
def open_json_data(file):
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
        new_data = json.load(json_file)
    return new_data
```

и вызывать функцию так:

```py
open_json_data("data.json")
```